# How to create an object from text file in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm doing an assignment where the user creates albums and songs within those albums. I need to add a feature that creates an album its songs from a text file (already given to us). The albums and songs are kept in Arrays, and there are set/get methods for all variables involved. The text file we get is formatted as follows, but contains multiple albums:

> Album Best of Queen
>
> Songs
>
> Name Bohemian Rhapsody
>   Artist Queen
>   Duration 354
>   Genre rock
>
> Name Under Pressure
>   Artist Queen
>   Duration 248
>   Genre rock

So far this is all I've got, which doesn't do anything.

```
void importAlbum() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String path;
        Scanner inputStream;

        System.out.println("Please type the name of the file you want to import (from same folder): ");
        path = console.nextLine();

        try {
            inputStream = new Scanner (new File(path));
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Error opening the file "+path);
        }

        while(inputStream.hasNextLine()){
            // Where to go
        }
    }
```

I'm just not sure how to read each line and send the variable to the correct set method. Would I have to have a BUNCH of if statements? But then how would it recognize that there are multiple albums in the text file.
PS. We can't use ArrayLists, only Arrays (I saw arraylists in some solutions online for this problem)
PPS. Let me know if I need to upload any other parts of the code (Sorry, I'm new to overflow/programming)

Comment: We will not do your homework for you. However, think of this just as you would if you were reading this from paper. The first line is the album name. Then you read a blank line, then read the word "Songs" then a blank line, then the song information.

Comment: You might have to check the beginning of each song title for the word Album as a key to stop reading songs and to start a new album. For your first draft, I'd use an ArrayList until you can figure out how to get the array sizes correct.

Comment: Thanks for that, appreciate the push in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your document is already structured, so you can follow that structure.

but instead of using a complex `if-else` construct, think in objects and methods!

- create a class `Album`
- create a class `Track`
- create a class `TextReader`
- create a class `TextParser`

when your `TextParser.parse()` is executed it checks the input (from your `TextReader`), wether is it an `Album` information or is it a `Track` information.

- is it an `Album` then create a new `Album`
- is it a `Track`, create a new `Track` add the `Track` to the `Album`

### NOTE

the solution posted here is strongly opinion-based, if you find better objects and methods please apply these!!

### Implemention hints

- try to split the lines into `InformationBlocks` a new `InformationBlock` has reached it's end, if a blank line occurs
- an `InformationBlock` can

  - be the Album Information (one line - but not `Songs`)
  - be the Song Information (one line: `Songs`)
  - be the track Information (four lines)
- the `InformationBlock` should be part of the `Parser`
- create a Test that verifies that dokuments with more than one album is working properly